# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't remember font settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

I set my font in VS2010 to Consolas 10 and it always works.
From last week, every time I opened a new instance of VS2010, the font is changed to something else (probably the default font?), but the font dialog says I'm still using Consolas 10.

[image]

To go back to Consolas, I have to set the font size to 11, click OK, then open the dialog and set it back to 10.

This is pretty annoying. Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Did you experience that problem in later versions too? Did you have Resharper installed? Was it only the fonts or even other settings that didn't get stored? I'm asking because [this reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332863/visual-studio-doesnt-remember-changes-to-settings)...

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't use later versions of VS so I'm not sure. Yes Resharper is installed. I just noticed fonts as it's really obvious. Other settings seems fine

Comment: Darn... Must be a different issue then... Too bad. How come you're not using VS15 or VS13? (I do agree they're butt ugly compared to the nice looks of VS10 but still...)