# Visual Studio doesn't remember changes to settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I've noticed that my VS15 forgets changes I make to the settings in options and check boxes under Tools on reboot.

For instance, when I exchange a string in a document, I get the pop-up telling my how many substitutions have been made. There's the check box showing/hiding this message next time. I uncheck it and fairly enough the pop-up doesn't come up again. Until I restart VS, that is. After that, the pop-up is back!

The same goes for many other options (typical NuGet packages' suggestion based on the contents of CSHTML-file, for instance). However, all the settings I make in Resharper menu are remembered. Also, the key short-cuts seem to be remembered.

I restarted, updated and reinstalled - no luck there. Starting VS in admin mode gives no change, neither. I noticed that if I change the values in the registry, the changes are effective in VS. It's like VS won't write the modified settings to the registry by itself (and I'm damn sure too chicken and too lazy to horse around in the registry for that).

1. Has anybody else experienced that?
2. What more can I do to diagnose it?
3. How do I kill the problem?